# systemd template units with different timers

Tags: systemd

I have several jobs, which I want systemd to start periodically but with an offset to each other.

Since the jobs are quite similar, I want to cover all of them with a single systemd template unit.

However, since the jobs might cause each some load, I want to disentangle the start times and use different systemd timers for each actual service.

Is there a way to hand over additional arguments (as a specific start time) during creating a service based on the template?

```
systemctl start MyGeneralService@Specific1.{AdditionalArgument??}.service
```

or is there a way to read a variable later to be used from within the unit template

```
[Service]
MyVar = {?XYZ?} /etc/MyService.d/%i.conf {?XYZ?}

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/{?MyVar?}
```

or is there any way to define dependencies in a template for derived services? I.e., Before=/After= of derived services in a dynamic(??) way

```
Specific2
[Service]
After=MyGeneralService@{?%i-1?}.service
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May I necropost here? :)

You need a [timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html), that one can create a bunch of for one service by specifying `Unit`. E.g:

```
# systemctl edit --full --force MyGeneralService-1w@.timer
...
[Timer]
Unit=MyGeneralService@%i.service
RandomizedDelaySec=30
OnActiveSec=5 #start on timer activation after 5 sec once 
OnUnitActiveSec=1w #start on timer activation each 1 week pass
...
```

If you want more generic (an dirty) way, you can pass 2nd arg by utilizing a [%j](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers) token:

1. Create a generic service/timer.
2. Make **hardlinks** to that service/timer with desired argument as last prefix word, delimited by `-`

Example:

```
# systemctl edit --full --force MyGeneralService@.timer
...
[Timer]
Unit=MyGeneralService@%i.service
OnUnitActiveSec=%J
...

# ln /etc/systemd/system/MyGeneralService@.timer /etc/systemd/system/MyGeneralService-1w@.timer
# ln /etc/systemd/system/MyGeneralService@.timer /etc/systemd/system/MyGeneralService-1d@.timer
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl show MyGeneralService-1w@foo.timer
...
Triggers=MyGeneralService@foo.service
TimersMonotonic={ OnUnitActiveUSec=1w ; next_elapse=0 }
...
# systemctl show MyGeneralService-1d@bar.timer
...
Triggers=MyGeneralService@bar.service
TimersMonotonic={ OnUnitActiveUSec=1d ; next_elapse=0 }
...
```

PS: Quick timers hands-on by [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)

Comment: uh, hardlinks are quite a nice hack - I like that ;)